# How can I make a plot reactive to a slider to change years in both extremes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dashboard, reactive

So I have a dataframe that has the information of how many accidents there were in a certain year and the amount that the insurance company had to pay each year. I've managed to create both plots (one for the accidents and another one for the amounts) with the years being in the x-axis in both plots, but now I´m making a Dashboard using Shiny and I'd like to make it reactive so the user can choose frome which years they want the information e.g. The information goes from 1999 to 2020 but I'd like the user to choose the years from a Slider input in case they want to see the info from just 2015 to 2020.

Here's part of the source of my code and I already have the input in Shiny, but I have no idea how to code the server part. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
df <- mydata %>%
  rename(Moneda="MONEDA", Estatus="ESTATUS") %>%
  data.frame()
fechas.Separadas <- setDT(df)[, Anio_Mes := format(as.Date(df$F_SINIESTRO), "%Y-%m") ]

dfAños <- df %>% 
  select("F_SINIESTRO", "Moneda", "Monto") %>%
  group_by(year(F_SINIESTRO)) %>%
  filter(any(Moneda==1, Moneda==2)) %>%
  summarise(Registros = n(), sumaMonto = sum(Monto, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  rename(Año = "year(F_SINIESTRO)", Monto = "sumaMonto")

lineasMontosAño <- ggplot(dfAños, aes(x=Año, y=Monto)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title="Monto total por año", x="Año", y="Montos totales")

lineasRegistrosAño <- ggplot(dfAños, aes(x=Año, y=Registros)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title="Registros totales por año", x="Año", y="Registros totales")
```